# Where can I find Azure TCO calculator file format sample?

Tags: azure, cost-management

I am trying to use Azure Total cost of ownership (TCO) calculator and could not find a link to documentation that provide details regarding what file formats are supported for bulk upload. 
 
Neither I could find any recommended sample Excel file format that I can readily use. 
 Ideally these documents or sample file format should be on the **Azure TCO calculator** page itself. 
Any pointers in this regards will be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bulk upload tool template hidden in the wizard. It would have been nice to also provide link to this template on the main page of Azure TCO calculator. 
 
You have to *click* on **Bulk Upload** tool and step 1 provide the template for uploading your inventory/discovery data.